# Why does $P(X+ Y =k) = \sum_{i = 0}^k P(X+ Y = k, X = i)$ hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can someone explain, intuitively or otherwise, why the following is true:

$$P(X+ Y =k) = \sum_{i = 0}^k P(X+ Y = k, X = i)\tag 1$$

How can the probability of $X+Y=k$ be the same as the probability of $X+Y=k$ and $X=i$ summed over $i=0,1,...,k?$ I can't seem to grasp this, apparently basic concept and it discourages me a lot.

Comment: $\{\omega\in \Omega : X(\omega)+Y(\omega) = k\} = \bigcup_{i=0}^k \{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)+Y(\omega)=k, \, X(\omega)=i \} $, and the sum is disjoint. That's of course if $X\in \{0, \, 1, \, ..., k\}$

Comment: Law of Total Probability.

Comment: @Clarinetist I know it is the LOTP with the partitions and stuff but I can't understand it. Apologies for not making it clear in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a try.

Your formula holds only if $X$ can take on non-negative integer values only.

Then it is just an algebraic way of saying, for instance (taking $k=3$)

> the chance I have 3 kids is equal to
>   the sum of the chance I have 3 girls and 0 boys plus the chance I have 2 girls and  1 boy plus the chance I have 1 girl and 2 boys plus the chance I have 0 girls and 3 boys.

Which itself is a probabilistic version of

> If I have 3 children, then exactly one of the following is true: I have 0 sons, I have 1 son, I have 2 sons, I have 3 sons.

Here $X$  and $Y$ stand for the number of male and female children I have, and the non-negative integer condition obviously holds.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you ver much!